# How can I get by GROK differents kind of messages in this litte log file?

Tags: design-patterns, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I am working with Logstash and I need to format my log file splitting each field.

The log has next format:

```
info: ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - ::ffff:127.0.0.1 [26/Jun/2019:11:52:36 +0000] "OPTIONS /api/categories/5ced18e2a0c9a01e879ce704 HTTP/1.1" 200 19 - 0.652

info: ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jun/2019:11:52:36 +0000] "GET /api/categories/5ced18e2a0c9a01e879ce704 HTTP/1.1" 304 - - 12.156

info: ::ffff:127.0.0.1 ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - [26/Jun/2019:11:52:36 +0000] "OPTIONS /api/twitter/5ced18e2a0c9a01e879ce704/1561463556535-1561549956535?from=0&size=10&orderType=desc&order=date&aggregations=true&timeSeriesInterval=1h HTTP/1.1" 200 8 - 0.874

error: ::ffff:127.0.0.1 ::ffff:127.0.0.1 ::ffff:127.0.0.1 [26/Jun/2019:11:52:36 +0000] "GET /api/twitter/5ced18e2a0c9a01e879ce704/1561463556535-1561549956535?from=0&size=10&orderType=desc&order=date&aggregations=true&timeSeriesInterval=1h HTTP/1.1" 400 43 - 9.044
```

This is the filter that I have been aplied for it in Logstash:

```
filter {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{WORD:type}: %{IP:ipclient} - %{IP:ipuser} [%{HTTPDATE:datetime}] \"%{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{WORD:httpversion}\" %{WORD:status} %{NUMBER:bytes} - %{NUMBER:responsetime}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
```

But this filter does not recognoise my log structure.

Any idea which pattern should solve the problem?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern:

`%{WORD:type}: %{IP:ipclient} - %{IP:ipuser} \[%{HTTPDATE:datetime}\] \"%{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{WORD}\/%{NUMBER:httpversion}\" %{WORD:status} %{NUMBER:bytes} - %{NUMBER:responsetime}`

1. Escape [ ]
2. `/` is not in `WORD` if I remember correctly. Also I'd just extract the version and remove the `http/` part

Generally the Grok Debugger in Kibana will be your best friend to debug this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you,  but When IpUser is a - or When bytes are a -  then the pattern does not work. Also,  I have tryed it on a working example as in your example and all fields are string, does not recognoise numbers as ints,  floats,...  Doy you know why? Thank you.